# std::array couldn't be auto initialized for a certain data list

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++20, stdarray

std::array couldn't be auto initialized for a certain data list:

```
    static constexpr auto k_strap4_function_setting = std::array{0xf0000000, 0x70000000};  // compile error
    static constexpr auto k_strap4_function_setting = std::array{0xe0000000, 0x70000000};  // compile error
    static constexpr auto k_strap4_function_setting = std::array{0xd0000000, 0x70000000};  // compile error
    static constexpr auto k_strap4_function_setting = std::array{0xc0000000, 0x70000000};  // compile error
    static constexpr auto k_strap4_function_setting = std::array{0xb0000000, 0x70000000};  // compile error
    static constexpr auto k_strap4_function_setting = std::array{0xa0000000, 0x70000000};  // compile error
    static constexpr auto k_strap4_function_setting = std::array{0x90000000, 0x70000000};  // compile error
    static constexpr auto k_strap4_function_setting = std::array{0x80000000, 0x70000000};  // compile error
    static constexpr auto k_strap4_function_setting = std::array{0x70000000, 0x70000000};  // good to work
    static constexpr auto k_strap4_function_setting = std::array{0x60000000, 0x70000000};  // good to work
    static constexpr auto k_strap4_function_setting = std::array{0x50000000, 0x70000000};  // good to work
    static constexpr auto k_strap4_function_setting = std::array{0x40000000, 0x70000000};  // good to work
```

here is the error log:

```
error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'array'
    static constexpr auto k_strap4_function_setting = std::array{0xf0000000, 0x70000000};
```

The only difference is the highest bit is "1" for the "compile error" define.

Does that error make sense?
Or is a bug for std::array.

Comment: `0x80000000` is an `unsigned int`, and `0x70000000` is an `int`.

Comment: What type do you want your array to have? You can control this, e.g. `0xf000000ul` will make your type an unsigned long.

Comment: (I am surprised more than one declaration&initialisation of `k_strap4_function_setting` is *good to work*.)

Comment: @greybeard, that registers are not defined together, I just copy that together.

Comment: @PepijnKramer, Yes, I am using that way (add suffix **ul)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of a hexadecimal integer literal without any suffix is the first out of the following list that is able to represent the exact value of the literal:

```
int
unsigned int
long
unsigned long
long long
unsigned long long
```

On a system with 32 bit wide `int`, the largest value representable by `int` is `0x7fffffff` and the largest value representable by `unsigned int` is `0xffffffff`. So all literals up to `0x7fffffff` have type `int` and those from `0x80000000` to `0xffffffff` have type `unsigned int`.

The deduction guide for `std::array` is specified in such a way that it will fail if not all elements of the initializer have the same type. And that is why some of your examples fail.

Either specify the element type of the array explicitly, e.g. `std::array<unsigned int>` instead of `std::array`, so that initializers with other types will be implicitly converted to the specified element type, or add `U` (or `u`) suffixes to your literals to force them always to choose only unsigned types from the list above.